# Preserve Order of select dropdown added by append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to dynamically add options to a `select`.

```js
$("input[name='config']").on('change', function () {
    let config = $("input[name='config']").val();
    let dropdown = $('#forumselect');
    let configlabel = $("#config_required-error");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {configpath: config, action: 'validateconfig'},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status === 'success') {
                $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                $("#inputadminid").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#configfield").removeClass("has-error");
                configlabel.css("display", "none");
                configlabel.empty();
                dropdown.empty();
                let count = 0;
                let disabled = false;
                $.each(data.nodes, function (key, entry) {
                    disabled = (entry.node_type_id === 'Category');
                    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').prop('value', entry.node_id).text(addpadding(entry.title,entry.depth)).prop('disabled', disabled));
                    count++;
                });
                dropdown.prop('size', count);
            } else {
                $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                $("#inputadminid").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#configfield").addClass("has-error");
                configlabel.css("display", "inline-block");
                configlabel.text(data.errortext);
                dropdown.empty();
                dropdown.prop('size', 0);
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Here is sample response data

```
{"status":"success","nodes":{"297":{"node_id":"297","node_type_id":"Category","title":"Papertrey Ink Forum","depth":"0","lft":"1"},"5":{"node_id":"5","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Stamp Release Parties","depth":"1","lft":"2"},"227":{"node_id":"227","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"February 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"3"},"231":{"node_id":"231","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"March 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"5"},"233":{"node_id":"233","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"April 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"7"},"235":{"node_id":"235","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"May 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"9"},"239":{"node_id":"239","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"June 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"11"},"241":{"node_id":"241","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"July 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"13"},"244":{"node_id":"244","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"August 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"15"},"247":{"node_id":"247","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"September 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"17"},"249":{"node_id":"249","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"October 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"19"},"251":{"node_id":"251","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"November 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"21"},"253":{"node_id":"253","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"December 2015 Release","depth":"2","lft":"23"},"255":{"node_id":"255","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"January 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"25"},"257":{"node_id":"257","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"February 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"27"},"259":{"node_id":"259","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"March 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"29"},"261":{"node_id":"261","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"April 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"31"},"263":{"node_id":"263","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"May 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"33"},"265":{"node_id":"265","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"June 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"35"},"269":{"node_id":"269","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"July 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"37"},"271":{"node_id":"271","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"August 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"39"},"275":{"node_id":"275","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"September 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"41"},"277":{"node_id":"277","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"October 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"43"},"279":{"node_id":"279","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"November 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"45"},"282":{"node_id":"282","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"December 2016 Release","depth":"2","lft":"47"},"284":{"node_id":"284","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"January 2017 Release","depth":"2","lft":"49"},"287":{"node_id":"287","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"March 2017 Release","depth":"2","lft":"51"},"289":{"node_id":"289","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"April 2017 Release","depth":"2","lft":"53"},"291":{"node_id":"291","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"May 2017 Release","depth":"2","lft":"55"},"293":{"node_id":"293","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"June 2017 Release","depth":"2","lft":"57"},"295":{"node_id":"295","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"July 2017 Release","depth":"2","lft":"59"},"9":{"node_id":"9","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Design Team Only","depth":"1","lft":"62"},"137":{"node_id":"137","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Moderator HQ","depth":"2","lft":"63"},"189":{"node_id":"189","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Make It Market Kit Co.","depth":"2","lft":"65"},"201":{"node_id":"201","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Stamp-a-faire 2014","depth":"2","lft":"67"},"221":{"node_id":"221","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Quick Stitch Kits","depth":"2","lft":"69"},"222":{"node_id":"222","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Moments Inked","depth":"2","lft":"71"},"223":{"node_id":"223","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Stamp-a-faire 2015","depth":"2","lft":"73"},"266":{"node_id":"266","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Stamp-a-faire 2016","depth":"2","lft":"75"},"13":{"node_id":"13","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"RAK","depth":"1","lft":"78"},"17":{"node_id":"17","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Gallery","depth":"1","lft":"80"},"16":{"node_id":"16","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Off Topic","depth":"1","lft":"82"},"30":{"node_id":"30","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Happy Birthday","depth":"2","lft":"83"},"26":{"node_id":"26","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"I Spy PTI","depth":"1","lft":"86"},"105":{"node_id":"105","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Make It Monday","depth":"1","lft":"88"},"140":{"node_id":"140","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Please Read - Registration Required","depth":"1","lft":"90"},"95":{"node_id":"95","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"For Sale\/Trade","depth":"1","lft":"92"},"273":{"node_id":"273","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"For Sale\/Trade","depth":"2","lft":"93"},"274":{"node_id":"274","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"In Search Of","depth":"2","lft":"95"},"281":{"node_id":"281","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Recipe Exchange","depth":"1","lft":"98"},"21":{"node_id":"21","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"All Things Scrapbooking","depth":"1","lft":"100"},"226":{"node_id":"226","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Stamping Talk","depth":"1","lft":"102"},"268":{"node_id":"268","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Stamp-a-faire 2016","depth":"2","lft":"103"},"18":{"node_id":"18","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Techniques & Tutorials","depth":"2","lft":"105"},"58":{"node_id":"58","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"File Sharing","depth":"2","lft":"107"},"29":{"node_id":"29","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Matching Colors","depth":"3","lft":"108"},"59":{"node_id":"59","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Crafty Spaces","depth":"2","lft":"111"},"60":{"node_id":"60","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Product Ideas & Questions","depth":"2","lft":"113"},"83":{"node_id":"83","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Blog Talk","depth":"2","lft":"115"},"96":{"node_id":"96","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Showcase Items","depth":"2","lft":"117"},"102":{"node_id":"102","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Holiday Central","depth":"2","lft":"119"},"123":{"node_id":"123","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Team Tips & Techniques","depth":"2","lft":"121"},"190":{"node_id":"190","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Organization","depth":"2","lft":"123"},"197":{"node_id":"197","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Website Questions","depth":"2","lft":"125"},"224":{"node_id":"224","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Misti Chatter","depth":"2","lft":"127"},"229":{"node_id":"229","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Moments Inked","depth":"2","lft":"129"},"238":{"node_id":"238","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Stitching Dies","depth":"2","lft":"131"},"15":{"node_id":"15","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"Blog Hop","depth":"1","lft":"134"},"278":{"node_id":"278","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"October 2016 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"135"},"280":{"node_id":"280","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"November 2016 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"137"},"283":{"node_id":"283","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"December 2016 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"139"},"285":{"node_id":"285","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"January 2017 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"141"},"286":{"node_id":"286","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"February 2017 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"143"},"288":{"node_id":"288","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"March 2017 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"145"},"290":{"node_id":"290","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"April 2017 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"147"},"292":{"node_id":"292","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"May 2017 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"149"},"294":{"node_id":"294","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"June 2017 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"151"},"296":{"node_id":"296","node_type_id":"Forum","title":"July 2017 Blog Hop","depth":"2","lft":"153"}},"errortext":""}
```

The problem is that I want to preserve the original order of the `nodes` array but it is always ordered by value.
AND HTML output is

```
<select multiple="" name="forums[]" id="forumselect" class="form-control mb-15" size="78">
   <option value="5">&nbsp; &nbsp; Stamp Release Parties</option>
   <option value="9">&nbsp; &nbsp; Design Team Only</option>
   <option value="13">&nbsp; &nbsp; RAK</option>
   <option value="15">&nbsp; &nbsp; Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="16">&nbsp; &nbsp; Off Topic</option>
   <option value="17">&nbsp; &nbsp; Gallery</option>
   <option value="18">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Techniques &amp; Tutorials</option>
   <option value="21">&nbsp; &nbsp; All Things Scrapbooking</option>
   <option value="26">&nbsp; &nbsp; I Spy PTI</option>
   <option value="29">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Matching Colors</option>
   <option value="30">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Happy Birthday</option>
   <option value="58">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; File Sharing</option>
   <option value="59">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Crafty Spaces</option>
   <option value="60">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Product Ideas &amp; Questions</option>
   <option value="83">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Blog Talk</option>
   <option value="95">&nbsp; &nbsp; For Sale/Trade</option>
   <option value="96">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Showcase Items</option>
   <option value="102">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Holiday Central</option>
   <option value="105">&nbsp; &nbsp; Make It Monday</option>
   <option value="123">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Team Tips &amp; Techniques</option>
   <option value="137">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Moderator HQ</option>
   <option value="140">&nbsp; &nbsp; Please Read - Registration Required</option>
   <option value="189">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Make It Market Kit Co.</option>
   <option value="190">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Organization</option>
   <option value="197">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Website Questions</option>
   <option value="201">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Stamp-a-faire 2014</option>
   <option value="221">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Quick Stitch Kits</option>
   <option value="222">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Moments Inked</option>
   <option value="223">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Stamp-a-faire 2015</option>
   <option value="224">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Misti Chatter</option>
   <option value="226">&nbsp; &nbsp; Stamping Talk</option>
   <option value="227">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; February 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="229">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Moments Inked</option>
   <option value="231">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; March 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="233">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; April 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="235">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; May 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="238">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Stitching Dies</option>
   <option value="239">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; June 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="241">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; July 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="244">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; August 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="247">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; September 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="249">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; October 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="251">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; November 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="253">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; December 2015 Release</option>
   <option value="255">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; January 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="257">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; February 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="259">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; March 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="261">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; April 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="263">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; May 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="265">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; June 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="266">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Stamp-a-faire 2016</option>
   <option value="268">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Stamp-a-faire 2016</option>
   <option value="269">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; July 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="271">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; August 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="273">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; For Sale/Trade</option>
   <option value="274">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; In Search Of</option>
   <option value="275">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; September 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="277">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; October 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="278">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; October 2016 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="279">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; November 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="280">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; November 2016 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="281">&nbsp; &nbsp; Recipe Exchange</option>
   <option value="282">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; December 2016 Release</option>
   <option value="283">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; December 2016 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="284">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; January 2017 Release</option>
   <option value="285">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; January 2017 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="286">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; February 2017 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="287">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; March 2017 Release</option>
   <option value="288">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; March 2017 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="289">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; April 2017 Release</option>
   <option value="290">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; April 2017 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="291">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; May 2017 Release</option>
   <option value="292">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; May 2017 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="293">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; June 2017 Release</option>
   <option value="294">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; June 2017 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="295">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; July 2017 Release</option>
   <option value="296">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; July 2017 Blog Hop</option>
   <option value="297" disabled="">Papertrey Ink Forum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The order of `option` elements in the select will always be the order you append them. If this is not the case then there must be some other sorting logic which is affecting the output.

Comment: Also note that you can just use `dropdown.prop('size', data.nodes.length)` without having to increment the `count` variable in the loop

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated the answer with full code .. sample json response and sample output .. I also tried    data.nodes.length    but it didn't work

Comment: Thank you for updating. The issue is because `nodes` is an object. The order of properties within an object is not guaranteed in any way. If you need to guarantee the order, change the data structure to an array instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan .. That was it .. thanks for your help .. I removed keys form the php array before using json_encode and it did it .. also data.nodes.length works now .. please add it as answer .. may be it can be useful to other people .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because the `nodes` property holds an object. While it's possible to loop through this, the order of properties within an object is not guaranteed in anyway, and can change at runtime - as you've now discovered.

To address this problem, change the `nodes` property to hold an array, as the order of elements within an array will never change unless you explicitly do so in code.